# Split payment from Stipe via platform account

Tags: stripe-payments, payment-gateway

I have a use case where the money collected from user via my platform needs to be charged directly in one of the connected account and then split the payment from the connected account as a application fee to my account and transfer to another connected account.
For some business reason , money cannot be charged in my platform account. Similar to direct charge however as per the stripe docs , direct charge involves only 1 user and my usecase needs more than 1 user.

Is there a way this can be achieved via Stripe connect in a simple?

Below is the sample flow
[image]

Comment: No a platform cannot move funds between two separate connected accounts as per your example. You'd need to transfer the $8 payment for connected account 2 from your platform.

Comment: ok so if my platform receives 8 USD and then transfer again to connected account 2 will that involves additional transfer cost ?

Comment: No there's no fees for transferring balances between Stripe account.